# Telerik: LoadOnDemand not working proerply

Tags: asp.net, linq, telerik, datasource

I have a LinqDataSource and a RadComboBox set up, so that the combobox shows the query results on demand. The table has 1000 or so rows and it takes a lot of time to load that page because for some reason RadComboBox keeps loading everything.

So what is wrong with the code below? I have nothing regarding cbAuto in the code-behind file

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
ContextTypeName="Webshop.Entities" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="Name, FromDate, TillDate"
Select="new (AutoID, Name, FromDate, TillDate, Comment)" TableName="Autos">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cbAutos" runat="server" Width="900px"
        DropDownWidth="900px" EmptyMessage="Chosse an autotype"
        HighlightTemplatedItems="True"
         Filter="Contains" LoadingMessage="Loading..." DataTextField="Name"
 MaxHeight="300px" DataValueField="AutoID" ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="False"
DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" EnableLoadOnDemand="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="True" 
ItemsPerRequest="100">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <table style="width: 850px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 300px;">Autotype</td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">Date (from)</td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">Date (till)</td>
                                        <td style="width: 150px;">Comment</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table style="width: 850px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 300px;">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromDate")%>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TillDate")%>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 150px;">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the another `Radcombobox` property `EnableAutomaticLoadOndemand=true` this could be help you solve your problem